# Receive object from handler in other activity

Tags: java, android, handler

I'm writing a simple chat application but i don't know how to use my main result handler from another activity. I'm setting resultHandler in main activity like this:

```
ResultHandler handler = new ResultHandler();
MGey.setUpdatesHandler(handler);
```

My ResultHandler.java has this code

```
public class ResultHandler {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ChatObject object)
    {
        //receive message object from server
    }
}
```

Now in my other activity (`Dialogs.java`) I want to use this handler to get updates.

For example: if my `onResult` method receive new message object (`ChatObject.NewMessage`) I want to use this object in my `Dialogs.java` for new message notification etc.

```
if (object instanceof ChatObject.NewMessage)
//pass this object to Dialogs activity
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: I can't send chatobject using intents because this is not serialized